# Azure ML Studio Web Service Always Returns the Same Prediction

Tags: azure, machine-learning

I'm currently working on a miniproject for my course, and I've run into a roadblock that I'm hoping to get some help with. After training an SVM model in Azure Machine Learning Studio and deploying it as a web service, I've encountered a peculiar issue—the service returns the same prediction regardless of the input data.

What might be going wrong?

https://gallery.cortanaintelligence.com/Experiment/Binary-Classifier-SVM-Web
https://gallery.cortanaintelligence.com/Experiment/Binary-Classifiers-SVM

Here's what I've done so far:

- Ensured all preprocessing steps are identical to those used during the model's training phase (including data normalization and handling of missing values).
- Double-checked that the model is being scored with the input data.
- Verified the web service's configuration, particularly in constructing responses to ensure no static value is being returned.
- Made sure the input data's format matches the expected schema. The model performs well within the ML Studio environment and predicts accurately with the test data. However, the deployed web service doesn't seem to reflect this behavior and outputs a constant value.

Answer (score 0):

Following steps can be used to fixed the mentioned issue

> 1. Verify that correct algorithm is used to train the model
> 2. Data used to train the model should contains maximum possible data inputs similar to real time data
> 3. Retrain the model with sufficient amount of data, the more amount of data used to train the model increases the changes of better prediction